# Is it legal for a non-profit to omit the salaries of their deputy director and other lower level directors on Form 990?

Tags: tax-law, non-profit, irs

I'm looking at a the Form 990 for a small non-profit, and I'm noticing that under administrative/management expenses only the Executive Director's salary is listed. I know there is a Deputy Director and a Director of Business Communications who draw salaries at the organization, but they are not listed. Is this legal? It's definitely misleading...

Answer (score 2):

For a small nonprofit, I'd assume that those positions would not need to be listed.

Under current IRS guidance, the organization must list:

1. **"All of its current officers, directors and trustees."** The positions you've mentioned do not appear to match any of these categories, at least as defined in the [Form 990 Glossary](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i990.pdf).
2. **"Up to 20 current employees who satisfy the definition of *key employee*."** Key employees are those with responsibilities similar to officers, directors, or trustees, and with compensation exceeding $150,000. For a small nonprofit, I'd be surprised if either of those positions you mentioned drew a salary exceeding $150,000, so I wouldn't expect either to need to be reported.
3. **"Its five current highest compensated employees with reportable compensation greater than $100,000."** On this question, it doesn't matter what the employee's responsibilities are. If their compensation exceeds $100,000, they should be included. But if those employees are making less than that, then no, they don't need to be listed.